# CJK bracket quotes for english text?

Tags: punctuation, cjk, csquotes

This is a MWE for german style quotes in english text. Now how can japanese bracket quotes be used using the enquote command? Or should another command be used? Also how do I install CJK taken from CTAN? Do I even need to install if all I want to use are the quotes? [In fact I do need to type both Chinese and Japanese text so I must load it anyway now, and I would like to use the quotes, but if there is a way to use CJK quotes without loading CJK, I would like to know about it too.]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=german]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\enquote{A phrase goes here.} I make a comment on it, which I quote, here. Isn't that nice? But it's in german quotes. What about nice japanese quotes?

\end{document}
```

Comment: How are Japanese and Chinese quotes obtained? You should use `CJKutf8`, anyway, not `CJK`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may read the documentation for `csquotes` which shows how to define an own quotation style. I don't know if the package CJK or any other Japanese package defines quotations. Have a look in their descriptions.

The symbols you are looking for are having the Unicode numbers 300C, 300D or for book titles 300E and 300F. If you find a [font for this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/300c/fontsupport.htm) you can just write a quotation command with use of `\newcommand{\jquote}[1]{{\setmainfont{someFont}\symbol{"300C}}#1{\setmainfont{someFont}\symbol{"300D}}}` or similar. (You will have to compile such a thing with Lua- or XeLaTeX and the package `fontspec` loaded)

As I am not having any cool font here, I just misused the ceiling and floor sign from mathmode. Just give it a try if this is already sufficient. (I guess not; not very beautiful. But you get the idea).

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\jquote}[1]{$\lceil$#1$\rfloor$}    

\begin{document}
\jquote{some Japanese quote} and \enquote{some English quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me the gist of how to proceed if I want to use different symbols or make my own "prettier" ones. Very useful. It works mostly as is: one can use tikz to add a white thick line to cover part of the symbol and reproduce varieties of the real symbol.